# Trying and failing to install Drush

Tags: software-installation, composer

I've got a fresh install of Ubuntu and I'm trying (and failing to install Drush). I've download LAMP and that all works fine. Then I installed Composer and that works fine. But when I try to install Drush I get numerous errors. Here's a log of what I did and what my results were. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? [Here's the link I was using to install](http://whaaat.com/installing-drush-8-using-composer).

First, I installed Curl, PHP5-CLI, and GIT, like so:

```
sudo apt-get install curl php5-cli git
```

I then installed Composer directly using:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-
dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

I ran 'composer' and that seemed to run fine.

I then tried to run this:

```
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

And got the following error:

```
[ErrorException]                                                             
  file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denie  
  d
```

I tried this then:

```
composer global require drush/drush:8
```

And got the same error.

Then I tried this:

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

And got the error:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘composer.phar’: No such file or directory
```

I then ran this (without error):

```
export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Then I ran this:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

And got this error:

```
bash: /home/pm3000/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: you should try `composer global require drush/drush:dev-master` with `sudo` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - that certainly seems to be the way to go. Terminal prompts me not to use sudo with composer but I did anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment above suggested (Thanks Thor!) I tried using sudo before my composer command and it gave me even further errors.

So then I followed the directions here and downloaded a specific version of Drush (drush:8.*) and that worked.